# I don't see my mounted DVD being listed when I use the ls command to list all that's on my Desktop

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, unix, dvd

I don't know if I did something wrong, but I was able to see the mounted DVD label name in Terminal when I did the ls command earlier while in my Desktop directory, now I can't, even though the DVD is mounted and I can see it on my Desktop. Ejected and remounted, too, still can't see it when I do ls.

All I wanted to do is to get into the mounted DVD and cp -R a folder in there onto my Desktop because I can't get to certain files by simply dragging *(The Finder can’t complete the operation because some data in “FileName” can’t be read or written. (Error code -36)”)* and read somewhere that I could try using cp -R command in Terminal. I'm pretty clueless in Unix/Terminal but gave it a shot after reading some instructions. At first I was at least able to ls and see all the files on my Desktop, including my mounted DVD name, but now it's gone. I don't know what happened. Please help? Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: Use the `mount` command to get a list of mounted devices and their mount points.  The mount point for the optical drive is the name of the directory that you want.  What version of *"Unix"* are you using?

Comment: I don't really know what version... but I just navigated into the DVD in Terminal by cd Volumes.

Answer (score 1):

In macOS the appearance of a mounted volume is only something that the Finder displays so you can access it easily without having to dig down into the filesystem to locate a mounted volume.

Like @sawdust said issuing the `mount` command will list all mounted volumes; but doing an `ls` in the `~Desktop/` directory should *not* show the mounted volumes. Why or how it showed up previously is unknown but **not** seeing a mounted volume in the directory listing of your desktop is expected behavior.

Comment: Ok thanks! - good to know that it's normal and that I didn't mess up something while fumbling in Terminal.